# Does PHP dynamically handle memory usage based on its limit?

Tags: php, memory, memory-management

I have a script that runs successfully when PHP's memory_limit is set to `50M` at about 25 seconds of runtime. When I print `memory_get_peak_usage` at the end of the script, it lands pretty closely to `50M`. When I set the memory_limit higher, to `90M`, `memory_get_peak_usage` shows around `75M` and the script loads about 10 seconds faster.

It seems intuitive that a script would use about the same amount of memory regardless of the memory_limit, but that doesn't seem to be the case. If a script maxes out at just under 50M with a limit of `50M`, I had expected the peak usage would be the same even though the memory_limit had been increased.

The only explanation I have is that PHP recognizes its close to its limit and spends time clearing unused memory in order to avoid hitting the limit. Is this how it actually works or have I just scratched the surface of something bigger?

Comment: I found this existing Q&A quite interesting in relation to your question: [Force freeing memory in PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2461762/367456). It scratches the topic of re-allocating memory which is most likely the issue here, too. However it depends on concrete code and you're not showing any so you're asking a bit into the blue here if what you experience is because the  garbage collector kicks in as well more often. http://lxr.php.net/xref/PHP_5_4/Zend/zend_alloc.c#1876

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you see is the garbage collector doing its job.

When you redefine a non-primitive variable value, the old value is not immediately discarded from memory. It remains there, as part of your script's memory usage.

Only when your script get dangerously close to its memory limit, is when the garbage collector is called to cleanup those unused pieces of allocated memory in order to free more space for the script. This process is coastly, and thats why the script will run faster with more memory - the garbage collector is not needed so often.

Edit:

Buffering takes part in this aswell. If your script is writing large amount of data to files, this data is first queued in memory, as your hard disk will not be able to write this data as fast as you generate it. If you are generating data much faster than the disk can write it, eventually the available memory will fill up and your program will be forced to wait next time you try to `fwrite()` or use any function that put data into buffers.

Comment: Is there any documentation supporting that? I was under the impression that PHP's garbage collector wasn't its main method of clearing memory.

Comment: Specific about when exactly it kicks in, not that I know of.  But it does exist and there are some facts about it you can find with a little Google research.

Answer (score 1):

i can't find hard proof of this but i remember/believe that memory_limit sets the amount of memory php will use per script vs memory_get_peak_usage shows memory allocated by your script (there is a slight difference in amount for the overhead which php uses to manage itself)

from the manual on [memory_get_peak_usage](http://php.net/manual/en/function.memory-get-peak-usage.php)

> **Parameters**
>
> real_usage
>
> Set this to TRUE to get the real size of memory allocated from system. If not set or FALSE only the memory used by emalloc() is reported.

Comment: `memory_get_peak_usage` shows the amount of memory allocated by my script. The `memory_limit` directive limits the amount of memory my script can use. You've got this much right. However, regardless of the `real_usage` parameter, the value of `memory_get_peak_usage` increases and the runtime of the script decreases simply when the `memory_limit` value is changed. I'd like to know why this is.

Comment: memory_limit directive limits the amount of memory your scripts execution environment can use (it includes the amount the environment uses to manage itself) therefore the amount your script can use is a little less

Comment: Oh ok, so it isn't that PHP is freeing memory to avoid hitting the limit - it's that PHP isn't giving memory to the environment that it otherwise would because the memory_limit is set low, right?

Comment: correct when less memory is available the php will restrict its on memory usage for things like file cache..